Why is my V-out 0.7V?
I am a university student and I am new to using switching regulators. I am trying to design a USB-C PDboard with the TPS552882 TI PMIC chip.
I am getting a voltage output of 0.7V. While I was reading through the data sheet, I realized I didn't connect the EN pin (I thought it was for programming and thought it had a internal pullup, bad idea to assume,) so I shorted it to 12V. I am still getting 0.7V on the output.
I plan on hooking DR1H up to an oscilloscope when I get my hands on one. My thought process is either A) DRH1 isn't switching at the right PWM, possibly because the EN pin isn't properly connected to the 12V rail (it's hard to solder with that package) or B) my feedback voltage isn't working properly.


Did you confirm your feedback resistor network is working properly? Are the GPIO pins pulling the signal to GND?

Are you sure the chip is soldered properly and the footprint is correct?

There could be an issue with your feedback. Check what voltage is on the FB pin.  Include a good-quality image of the assembled device. Also confirm what's happening with the GPIOs
